# Class Template specialization for multiple types

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I found a few questions that ask something similar but could not find a straight answer for my particular case.
The whole syntax for Templates is very confusing to me so I may just misunderstood something.

I have a class template that is supposed to accept every type.
Simple example:

```cpp
template <class T>
class State {
  public:
    void set(T newState);
    T get();
  private:
    T state;
};

template <class T>
void State<T>::set(T newState){
  state = newState;
}

template <class T>
T State<T>::get(){
  return state;
}
```

Now I would like to have a specialised template for a group of types that adds an additional function for these types. From what I found out so far I can utilize so called type_traits but how exactly they are used to achieve this is still a mystery to me.

F.e. this specialization for the int type but instead of writing this just for the int type I would also like to allow all other int and float variants. I found std::is_arithmetic but have no Idea how to utilize it to achieve this.

```cpp
template <>
class State <int> {
  public:
    void set(int newState);
    int get();
    int multiplyState(int n);
  private:
    int state;
};

void State<int>::set(int newState){
  state = newState;
}

int State<int>::get(){
  return state;
}

int State<int>::multiplyState(int n){
  return state*n;
}
```

Comment: lookup `std::enable_if`, *sfinae* and *partial specialization* ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use partial template specialization in combination with SFINAE to achieve this:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <class T, typename = void>
class State
{
    T state;

public:
    void set(T newState)
    {
        state = newState;
    }

    T get()
    {
      return state;
    }
};

template <typename T>
class State<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<T>>>
{
    T state;

public:
    void set(int newState)
    {
        state = newState;
    }

    int get()
    {
        return state;
    }

    int multiplyState(int n)
    {
        return state*n;
    }
};
```

[live example here](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAKxAEZSAbAQwDtRkBSAJgCFufSAZ1QBXYskwgA5NwDMeFsgYisAag6yAwgQCeAB0wB9AsSaFBG7BwAMAQRu2CmALZ7mT9VqVNBg1QBVSVV0DFiZnTE8AEVUAN1Q8dEsHb19VAGUCJicHDgB2PjtVYoDVQSyc2UL7Oz0RACMGPGQQBxK4hPQyzAIIf1UWTAB3TOzMAEo2kvzq9vbyseiB4dHK2em8qNyikv7gHohJneKZqfbiHrEWMorMDXWTzdynqu3HFzdFjW19TDCIgLJOypPyrSLfQI3dAgEB/JiNIx4ABmxm%2B5WhIDwgkMTGIhAQEQIzUMsQhyVkVgpzwepQWazedUazVaxw6iW6vQUBGWI1uR1s7VOrPmtyWg15Y3uZ3UTzs0q5qn2vX5goK0vOl2I1zpd1erPyWzlrIVzhEDCJbh0YIgCpYKo2NI1BCuNzGACoWFL9bL7C9qm94uynOVDtTpeViCJkNz0jK%2BH7pdKwd90pZVEwvTUBSVk1ouWn6pn2vUAHSm814S3WgAsXEmet9htsUnGjGkAFYpKQWNJrF3UNJNPx%2BGVROJwVxZLQuwRey3WwBrEDtgCcJdoG4AbCvaHlrNW8puABy0LhtqTVrvOOjWazduekAdSLuCEB32dSPutuCwJBoVx4AwmBkBQED/nogHASAwBHrIpBIoBTjEK%2BED1A%2B9QKLiOjSNOpD/hELAEAA8iwDDYZ%2BXZYM4rDAEBD74Bc0Z4LEmCvhRpCYAAHpgyAiE4OFdlymAMA%2BTT1KYxA6JoGCSFIuEmHg15yS2jA0Sgw68IweD1K%2BkCtqgehEqgLBsQAtOiGhRJwvD8LuqimURsgvmOEh0K2IlSJ297sU%2BnFHpupmbtWirIMgqhHiWsiqBAuCECQ6iTvQqjSQBQHEAlU7jMlGk8DOc7jIuIDVtYJZHmVsjWEeXAru2iVleel7eX2j7SC%2Bb6kB%2BX7udIXBXjed49j5rUdflrYscheDGUVQA%3D%3D%3D)

The trick here lies in the use of the second template parameter (which can be unnamed and is given a default argument). When you use a specialization of your class template, e.g., `State<some_type>`, the compiler has to figure out which of the templates should be used. To do so, it has to somehow compare the given template arguments with each template and decide which one is the best match.

The way this matching is actually done is by trying to deduce the arguments of each partial specialization from the given template arguments. For example, in the case of `State<int>`, the template arguments are going to be `int` and `void` (the latter is there because of the default argument for the second parameter of the primary template). We then try to deduce the arguments for our sole partial specialization

```
template <typename T>
class State<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<T>>>;
```

from the template arguments `int, void`. Our partial specialization has a single parameter `T`, which can directly be deduced from the first template argument to be `int`. And with that, we're already done as we have deduced all parameters (there is only one here). Now we substitute the deduced parameters into the partial specialization: `State<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<T>>>`. We end up with `State<int, void>`, which matches the list of initial arguments of `int, void`. Therefore, the partial template specialization applies.

Now, if, instead, we had written `State<some_type>`, where `some_type` is not an arithmetic type, then the process would be the same up to the point where we have successfully deduced the parameter for the partial specialization to be `some_type`. Again, we substitute the parameter back into the partial specialization `State<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<T>>>`. However, `std::is_arithmetic_v<some_type>` will now be `false`, which will lead to `std::enable_if_t<…>` not being defined and substitution fails. Since [substituion failure is not an error](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) in this context, this simply means that the partial specialization is not an option here and the primary template will be used instead.

If there were multiple matching partial specializations, they then would have to be ranked to pick the best match. [The actual process](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.class.order) is quite complicated, but it generally boils down to picking the most concrete specialization.

Comment: Could you explain what the second argument(?) means in the case of `<class T, typename = void>` and `class State <T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<T>>>` I have trouble finding a good explanation of this syntax.

Comment: @PTS I updated my answer with what hopefully is a useful explanation.

Comment: Thank you for the further explanation.

Unfortunately this doesn't compile with C++11. I tried `enable_if` and `is_arithmetic` instead https://godbolt.org/z/VocB39 but that doesn't seem to be valid. Does this require C++17 or does it have to constructed differntly for C++11?

Comment: This https://godbolt.org/z/1qgSY1 seems to compile but then fails to use the specialization but instead seem to use the base template.

Comment: My example does indeed require C++17. For C++11 you would have to use `typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value>::type>`.

Comment: @PTS the mistake in your version is that you're using the type `std::enable_if<…>` itself as the argument rather than `std::enable_if<…>::type`.

Comment: Hm, doesn't seem to like this either or I misunderstood you: https://godbolt.org/z/nT8n1b

Comment: Ugh yes sorry, you wrote that. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 3):

While for a small example like this it's fine to specialize the whole class, in more complicated cases you might be interested in avoiding having to duplicate all the members just so you can add one member to the specialization. To that end, a common technique is to inherit the extra member functions from a public base class, and specialize only the base class to either have or not have the members. You have to use CRTP so that the base class member functions know how to access the derived class. This looks like:

```
// StateBase only contains the extra multiplyState member when State tells it to
// define it, based on T being an arithmetic type
template <class D, class T, bool has_multiply>
struct StateBase {};

template <class D, class T>
struct StateBase<D, T, true> {
    T multiplyState(int n) {
        return static_cast<D*>(this)->state * n;
    }
};

template <class T>
class State : public StateBase<State<T>, T, std::is_arithmetic<T>::value> {
  public:
    // no need to duplicate these declarations and definitions
    void set(T newState);
    T get();
  private:
    // note that we write State::StateBase to force the injected-class-name to be found
    friend struct State::StateBase;
    T state;
};
```

[Coliru link](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0663fba40e4f8ea7)

Comment: Thank you, this would have indeed been my next question.

Comment: Could you maybe explain the use of structs here? This not a familiar concept to me but I see the use of structs a lot in conjunction with Class Templates.
Does this work like creating a partial part of a class that get inserted into the actual class defintion by the compiler?

Comment: @PTS A struct is just a class that defaults to public access for its members and base classes.

Comment: Oh right I remember that vaguely. I was not aware of the concept of friends in C++ :)